# Access localhost on a PC from mobile connected using bluetooth/wifi

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I want my localhost folder on my pc to be accessible by mobile phone connected using bluetooth/wifi. I am using WAMP. How do I do this?

Answer (score 13):

Since you are using **`WAMP`**. This is possible.

Just click your **`WAMP`** icon on your system tray and choose the option "**Put Online**".

After doing so, go to your command prompt (`Start -> Run -> Cmd [Press Enter]` ) . Now type the command **`ipconfig`**. You will see your system's IP. Make note of that IP. Say your IP is 192.XXX.XXX.XX.

Now you can access your localhost files as `http://192.XXX.XXX.XX/myfile.php` which is synonymous to `http://localhost/myfile.php`

This URL can be accessed even from outside world. So be cautious ! :)

Comment: I tried this it working fine but `databse` could't connect

Comment: <This URL can be accessed even from outside world. So be cautious ! :) -> Not true completely.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a guide how to access your website through mobile:

http://www.logicspot.com/web-development-2/viewing-a-locally-hosted-website-with-your-smartphone/

Comment: Posting links are not future proof - websites can sometimes cease to exist

Comment: ... just like in that case

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is perfect solution or not but if I would be at your place then I would have done like follows.

1) 1st suppose your project is in www or htdocs folder. Decide if you want to see all projects or just only one project you are working on, on mobile connected with wifi. (I am not sure if this works with Bluetooth.)

2) For all projects if your projects in www/htdocs then right click on folder and go in properties. (I assume you are using windows as you mentioned wamp server). Now on properties window click on sharing tab. And click share.  I assume you shared "www" folder.

3) one window will open saying "choose people to share with", click on drop down list and select everyone. Then click on "Add" button.

4) now check your pc name, you can check it by right clicking my computer and properties. In properties window look for "Computer name". Suppose it is saneshcomputer.

5) Now open browser in your mobile and type following url
http://sanesh.computer/www/ (Please do not use dot in sanesh and computer, it wasn't allowing me to post answer so I had to put dot there.)

IT should work, you should able to see your localhost screen. If you wanted for only single project then instead of using www use project folder name in thee link I just gave you.

If it didn't worked then let me know.